# Are the numbers $\sqrt{n^2 + q^2}$, $n=0,1,\dots$, linearly dependent over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $q$ be a non-zero rational number, and consider the set of numbers $\sqrt{n^2 + q^2}$, with $n=0,1,\dots$. Are they linearly dependent over $\mathbb{Q}$? In other terms, can we find some positive integer $N$ and some rational numbers $a_0,\dots,a_N$ not all equal to zero, such that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^{N} a_N \sqrt{n^2 + q^2} = 0?
\end{equation}
I found this statement in the post [Linear Independence of Square Roots over Q](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/156360/linear-independence-of-the-square-roots-over-q), where the author of the post considers it "evident". For me, not only it is not evident at all, but I have some serious doubt that it is generally true.
What do you think about it?

Thank you very much for your attention in advance.

**NOTE**. Let us recall, in connection with this problem, that we have the following remarkable result.

**Theorem** Let $n_1,\dots,n_k$ be square-free integers. Then the numbers $\sqrt{n_1},\dots,\sqrt{n_k}$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$ if and onfly if $n_1,\dots,n_k$ are pairwise distinct.

Elementary proofs of this result are given in [Linear Independence of Radicals](http://abel.harvard.edu/hcmr/issues/2.pdf) by Iurie Borieco, then a young pluri-medallist at the International Mathematical Olympiads.

Comment: Do you know Galois theory?

Comment: @EDX Unfortunately not for now!

Comment: Out of Galois theory see if https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion could help you with $ P =\prod (X^2-(n^2+q^2))$

Comment: Dear @EDX, I cannot see how by studying the irreducibility of this polynomial, we can find a solution to our problem, nor I see how Eisenstein' criterion can be of some help. If you have some solution in mind, please write it down as an answer and I will try to understand it, but these little hints are not of great help for me, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very interesting problem.

Let $q=A/B (A,B \in \mathbb{Z})$. I claim there exists $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\sqrt{A^2+q^2}$ and $\sqrt{(Ax)^2+q^2}$ are linearly dependent, meaning that there exist $y \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $(Ax)^2 + A^2/B^2 = y^2 (A^2 + A^2/B^2)$, which is equivalent to $B^2x^2 - (B^2+1)y^2 = -1.$

Let $d = B^2+1$.
Then the problem is to find units $p+q\sqrt{d}$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ such that $B|p$ and with norm $-1$.
We have $u=B+\sqrt{d}$ as a trivial solution, corresponding to $(x,y)=(1,1)$.

Then consider $u^3 = (B+\sqrt{d})^3 = (B^3+3Bd) + (3B^2+d)\sqrt{d}$, giving $(x,y)=(B^2+3d,3B^2+d) = (4B^2+3,4B^2+1).$

Explicitly, $ \sqrt{(4AB^2+3A)^2 + (A/B)^2} = (4B^2+1) \sqrt{A^2+(A/B)^2}$.

Comment: Dear @aerile, this is really remarkable!!! I could never imagined that such a beautiful solution could have been given to such a problem! I thank you very very very ... much for your invaluable help!

Answer (score 6):

Guided by the pythagorean triples $(9,12,15)$ and $(5,12,13)$, we can take $q=12$ and have
$$\sqrt{5^2+12^2}-\frac{13}{15}\sqrt{9^2+12^2}=0.$$
Many pythagorean triples lend themselves to this.

I wonder if any counter-examples are not derived from a pythagorean triple...

Comment: Dear @HeathWinning, thank you ver much for having kindly replied to my question with a very nice example. Anyway, it does NOT answer  my question, which asks whether the numbers $\sqrt{n^2 + q^2}$, with $n=0,1,\dots$ turn out to be linearly dependent over $\mathbb{Q}$ for EVERY choice of the non-zero rational number $q$.

Comment: By the way, you do not need to get a pythagorean triple in order to have linearly dependent radicals. For example, take $q=1$, and $n=1,7$. Then we have $5 \sqrt{1^2+1^2}  - \sqrt{1^2 + 7^2} = 0$.